# Android checkbox style

Tags: android, android-layout, checkbox, styles, themes

I am new to android and I'm trying to set a style to all check boxes in my application. My application style is set to Theme.Holo which is dark and I would like the check boxes on my list view to be of style Theme.Holo.Light. I am not trying to create a custom style. The code below doesn't seem to work, nothing happens at all. I need to do this because my list view has a light paper texture and the check box and check box text is white which i would like dark.

```
<style name="CustomActivityTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:checkboxStyle">@style/customCheckBoxStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="customCheckBoxStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.CompoundButton.CheckBox">
</style>
```

Also can you set styles to individual widgets if you set a style to the application?

Answer (score 123):

**Note**: Using Android Support Library v22.1.0 and targeting API level 11 and up? Scroll down to the last update.

---

> My application style is set to Theme.Holo which is dark and I would
>   like the check boxes on my list view to be of style Theme.Holo.Light.
>   I am not trying to create a custom style. The code below doesn't seem
>   to work, nothing happens at all.

At first it may not be apparent why the system exhibits this behaviour, but when you actually look into the mechanics you can easily deduce it. Let me take you through it step by step.

First, let's take a look what the `Widget.Holo.Light.CompoundButton.CheckBox` style defines. To make things more clear, I've also added the 'regular' (non-light) style definition.

```
<style name="Widget.Holo.Light.CompoundButton.CheckBox" parent="Widget.CompoundButton.CheckBox" />

<style name="Widget.Holo.CompoundButton.CheckBox" parent="Widget.CompoundButton.CheckBox" />
```

As you can see, both are empty declarations that simply wrap `Widget.CompoundButton.CheckBox` in a different name. So let's look at that parent style.

```
<style name="Widget.CompoundButton.CheckBox">
    <item name="android:background">@android:drawable/btn_check_label_background</item>
    <item name="android:button">?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple</item>
</style>
```

This style references both a background and button drawable. `btn_check_label_background` is simply a 9-patch and hence not very interesting with respect to this matter. However, `?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple` indicates that some attribute based on the **current theme** (this is important to realise) will determine the actual look of the `CheckBox`.

As `listChoiceIndicatorMultiple` is a theme attribute, you will find multiple declarations for it - one for each theme (or none if it gets inherited from a parent theme). This will look as follows (with other attributes omitted for clarity):

```
<style name="Theme">
    <item name="listChoiceIndicatorMultiple">@android:drawable/btn_check</item>
    ...
</style>

<style name="Theme.Holo">
    <item name="listChoiceIndicatorMultiple">@android:drawable/btn_check_holo_dark</item>
    ...
</style>

<style name="Theme.Holo.Light" parent="Theme.Light">
    <item name="listChoiceIndicatorMultiple">@android:drawable/btn_check_holo_light</item>
    ...
</style>
```

So this where the real magic happens: based on the theme's `listChoiceIndicatorMultiple` attribute, the actual appearance of the `CheckBox` is determined. The phenomenon you're seeing is now easily explained: since the appearance is theme-based (and **not** style-based, because that is merely an empty definition) and you're inheriting from `Theme.Holo`, you will always get the `CheckBox` appearance matching the theme.

Now, if you want to change your `CheckBox`'s appearance to the Holo.Light version, you will need to take a copy of those resources, add them to your local assets and use a custom style to apply them.

As for your second question:

> Also can you set styles to individual widgets if you set a style to the application?

Absolutely, and they will override any activity- or application-set styles.

> Is there any way to set a theme(style with images) to the checkbox
>   widget. (...) Is there anyway to use this selector: [link](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/drawable/btn_check_holo_light.xml)?

---

**Update:**

Let me start with saying again that you're not supposed to rely on Android's internal resources. There's a reason you can't just access the internal namespace as you please.

However, a way to access system resources after all is by doing an id lookup by name. Consider the following code snippet:

```
int id = Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("btn_check_holo_light", "drawable", "android");
((CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkbox)).setButtonDrawable(id);
```

The first line will actually return the resource id of the `btn_check_holo_light` drawable resource. Since we established earlier that this is the button selector that determines the look of the `CheckBox`, we can set it as 'button drawable' on the widget. The result is a `CheckBox` with the appearance of the `Holo.Light` version, no matter what theme/style you set on the application, activity or widget in xml. Since this sets only the button drawable, you will need to manually change other styling; e.g. with respect to the text appearance.

Below a screenshot showing the result. The top checkbox uses the method described above (I manually set the text colour to black in xml), while the second uses the default theme-based `Holo` styling (non-light, that is).

[image: Screenshot showing the result]

---

**Update2:**

With [the introduction of Support Library v22.1.0](http://android-developers.blogspot.nl/2015/04/android-support-library-221.html), things have just gotten a lot easier! A quote from the release notes (my emphasis):

> Lollipop added the ability to overwrite the theme at a view by view level by using the `android:theme` XML attribute - incredibly useful for things such as dark action bars on light activities. Now, AppCompat allows you to use `android:theme` for Toolbars (deprecating the `app:theme` used previously) and, **even better, brings `android:theme` support to all views on API 11+ devices.**

In other words: you can now apply a theme on a *per-view* basis, which makes solving the original problem a lot easier: just specify the theme you'd like to apply for the relevant view. I.e. in the context of the original question, compare the results of below:

```
<CheckBox
    ...
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo" />

<CheckBox
    ...
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light" />
```

The first `CheckBox` is styled as if used in a dark theme, the second as if in a light theme, regardless of the actual theme set to your activity or application.

Of course you should no longer be using the Holo theme, but instead use Material.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond. I see the issue here and I'm still wondering if this can be done with out me having to do a lot of work. Is there any way to set a theme(style with images) to the checkbox widget. I know that I can find the images and include them in my project but it seems like over kill. Is there anyway to use this selector:  https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/drawable/btn_check_holo_light.xml

Comment: @user1330739: Yes and no. You're not supposed to rely on internal resources as Google may decide to change them in future releases. Including a copy of the drawables in your local resources is really your best option. That being said, there is another (ugly) solution I'm aware of, but that only works at runtime (meaning you cannot reference it in your xml files). Please see the edit to my answer above.

Comment: Excellent answer. Update2 worked for me while trying to support API 19+.

Answer (score 62):

Maybe this will satisfy you -

**something.xml**

```
<CheckBox
    android:text="Custom CheckBox"
    android:button="@drawable/checkbox_selector"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

**Selector**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/star_down" />
    <item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@drawable/star" />
</selector>
```

[Source code credits here](http://www.hrupin.com/2011/09/how-to-make-android-checkbox-and-radiobutton-custom-style)

Answer (score 41):

The correct way to do it for Material design is :

Style :

```
<style name="MyCheckBox" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">  
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/foo</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/bar</item>
</style>
```

Layout :

```
<CheckBox  
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:checked="true"
    android:text="Check Box"
    android:theme="@style/MyCheckBox"/>
```

It will preserve Material animations on Lollipop+.

Comment: It makes sense to do it like this. Is there a way to globally set the theme for a checkbox then though?

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps you want something like:

```
<style name="CustomActivityTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:checkboxStyle">@style/customCheckBoxStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="customCheckBoxStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.CompoundButton.CheckBox">
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/black</item>
</style>
```

Note, the textColor item.

Answer (score 1):

In the previous answer also in the section `<selector>...</selector>` you may need:

```
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/checkbox_pressed" ></item>
```

Answer (score 0):

main_activity.xml

```
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/myCheckBox"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="@style/CustomCheckBoxStyle"
    android:text="My Checkbox" />
```

checkbox_style.xml

```
<style name="CustomCheckBoxStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.CompoundButton.CheckBox">
    <!-- Customize the checkbox's attributes -->
    <item name="android:button">@drawable/custom_checkbox</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">8dp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#FF0000</item>
    <!-- Add more custom attributes as needed -->
</style>
```

custom_checkbox.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/checkbox_checked" android:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/checkbox_unchecked" />
</selector>
```