# Android: Set color of CheckBox

Tags: android, android-layout

I've searched a number of places and don't seem to be able to figure out the `CheckBox` drawable for the border of the check box. Can anyone point me in the correct direction?

Here is what it looks like unchecked (Can barely see the box)

[image]

Here is the checked state

[image]

Here is what I'm trying to make it look like.

[image]

Comment: you can set image as background to checkBox.so take image having border and set background of it.

Comment: Setting the `android:buttonTint="@color/mybrown"` is an easy way to change the checkbox color.

Comment: android:buttonTint="@color/mybrown" does change the color of check box border. The only drawback is , it also changes the color of the tick which you may not want.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You can use a custom check box xml file for this. Save the below xml code in `drawables` folder, name it `custom_checkbox.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true" 
        android:drawable="@drawable/cbchk_blue"
        android:state_focused="false">
    </item>
    <item android:state_checked="true" 
        android:drawable="@drawable/cbchk_blue"
        android:state_focused="true">
    </item>
    <item android:state_checked="false" 
        android:drawable="@drawable/cbunchk_blue"
        android:state_focused="false">
    </item>
    <item android:state_checked="false" 
        android:drawable="@drawable/cbunchk_blue"
        android:state_focused="true">
    </item>
</selector>
```

Then use this file as background of your checkbox like this:

```
       <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:button="@drawable/custom_checkbox"
        android:id="@+id/checkBox" />
```

Here I am uploading my own images which I used in place of **cbchk_blue** and **cbunchk_blue**

[image: Unchecked CheckBox]
[image: Checked CheckBox]

Comment: Makes a lot of sense seeing it laid out like that. I had a lot of trouble finding good examples.

Comment: Ughhhh, why does width and height need to be explicitly specified for a checkbox, but for any other view I've used a shape definied in a (rectangular) drawable for its background resource, the view's background color would assume the shape's "solid" attribute value, and the "stroke" would paint the view's perimeter perfectly. I find with a checkbox, if width/height are omitted, then the shape collapses to 0 !!! Thanks.

Comment: an addition set the selector as the button drawable of the checkbox.

Comment: If some noob like me finds this answer and and doesn't now how to use it: create an xml-file in your drawable directory, copy-paste the coding above, and set the created style as button-property (filename of the xml=style-name) for your checkbox. see http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList for details

Comment: @user2345998 I edited the answer to make it more clear.

Answer (score 34):

Same problem also happens when you use theme Holo Dark for Activity and white background. So checkbox has Dark style. Simple workaround is directly set background from Android's Holo Light:

```
int id = Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("btn_check_holo_light", "drawable", "android");
checkBox.setButtonDrawable(id);
```

You can find great overview how all this things work in following answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/10139809/1170154

Comment: Exactly what I've been looking for the past few hours. Thanks!!

Comment: this should be the excepted answer. exactly what i needed

Comment: Helped me a lot! Thanks stranger!

Comment: I'll just throw in a me too on this as well.  This is much easier to implement than the accepted answer.  I'm developing in Xamarin.

Answer (score 27):

Since Android 5 and API level 21 it is possible to freely choose colors of checkboxes (and many other widgets). Add the following to your `values-v21/styles.xml` (while making sure you have a fallback for earlier APIs in `values/styles.xml`:

```
<style name="CustomCheckBox">
    <item name="android:theme">@style/CheckBoxAppTheme</item>
</style>

<style name="CheckBoxAppTheme">
    <item name="android:colorAccent">
        @color/theFillColorInCheckedState
    </item>
    <item name="android:colorControlNormal">
        @color/theBorderColorInUncheckedState
    </item>
    <item name="android:colorControlHighlight">
        @color/theBackgroundColorWhenFocusingTheCheckBox
    </item>
</style>
```

Then you just have to apply the style to your checkbox in your layout:

```
<CheckBox
    style="@style/CustomCheckBox" />
```

That's it, the checkboxes appear in your favourite colours!

Comment: I think you are missing `android:colorControlActivated`.

Comment: @Phoca, how to create a fallback style for version prior level 21?

Comment: For styles prior level 21 you set only `<item name="colorAccent>`, `<item name="colorControlNormal>` and import `    `compile com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1`

Comment: this solution worked for me when finally noticed is colorAccent is in the 'android:theme' and not styles.

Answer (score 15):

Ok, so I'm sorry but most of these answers are incomplete or have some minor bug in them.  'Styling' controls across different versions of Android is an **epic** pain in the ass.  After pulling my hair out for days on a project with very tight design constraints I finally broke down and wrote a test app and then really dug in and tested the various solutions out there for styling switches and check-boxes, since when a design has one it frequently has the other.  Here's what I found...

**First:** You can't actually style either of them, but you can apply a theme to all of them, or just one of them.

**Second:** You can do it all from XML and you don't need a second values-v21/styles.xml.

**Third:** when it comes to switches you have two basic choices if you want to support older versions of Android (like I'm sure you do)...

1. You can use a `SwitchCompat` and you will be able to make it look the same across platforms.
2. You can use a `Switch` and you will be able to theme it with the rest of your theme, or just that particular switch and on older versions of Android you'll just see an unstyled older square switch.

Ok now for the simple reference code.  Again if you create a simple Hello World! and drop this code in you can play to your hearts content.  All of that is boiler plate here so I'm just going to include the XML for the activity and the style...

activity_main.xml...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.kunai.switchtest.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="'Styled' SwitchCompat" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
        android:id="@+id/switch_item"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="46dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:checked="true"
        android:longClickable="false"
        android:textOff="OFF"
        android:textOn="ON"
        app:switchTextAppearance="@style/BrandedSwitch.text"
        app:theme="@style/BrandedSwitch.control"
        app:showText="true" />

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.kunai.switchtest.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Themed SwitchCompat" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
        android:id="@+id/switch_item2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="46dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:checked="true"
        android:longClickable="false" />

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.kunai.switchtest.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Themed Switch" />

    <Switch
        android:id="@+id/switch_item3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="46dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:checked="true"
        android:longClickable="false"
        android:textOff="OFF"
        android:textOn="ON"/>

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.kunai.switchtest.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="'Styled' Switch" />

    <Switch
        android:id="@+id/switch_item4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="46dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:checked="true"
        android:longClickable="false"
        android:textOff="OFF"
        android:textOn="ON"
        android:theme="@style/BrandedSwitch"/>

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.kunai.switchtest.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="'Styled' CheckBox" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkbox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="46dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:checked="true"
        android:longClickable="false"
        android:theme="@style/BrandedCheckBox"/>

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.kunai.switchtest.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Themed CheckBox" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkbox2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="46dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:checked="true"
        android:longClickable="false"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

styles.xml...

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">#3F51B5</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#303F9F</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">#FF4081</item>
</style>

<style name="BrandedSwitch.control" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!-- active thumb & track color (30% transparency) -->
    <item name="colorControlActivated">#e6e600</item>
    <item name="colorSwitchThumbNormal">#cc0000</item>
</style>

<style name="BrandedSwitch.text" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:textColor">#ffa000</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">9dp</item>
</style>

<style name="BrandedCheckBox" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="colorAccent">#aaf000</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">#ff0000</item>
</style>

<style name="BrandedSwitch" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="colorAccent">#39ac39</item>
</style>
```

I know, I know, you are too lazy to build this, you just want to get your code written.  I get it.  Here's what it looks like when you run it...

API_21:

[image: API 21]

API_18:

[image: API18]

Comment: This is a perfect answer. Made my life easy. This should be the accepted one.

Comment: This is the perfect answer to all the solutions here in this post.

Answer (score 7):

You can set the **CHECKBOX color** like this **API21 & Above**

> android:buttonTint="@color/YOUR_COLOR"

```
<CheckBox
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:buttonTint="@color/YOUR_COLOR" />
```

For the **support of Older version** use **AppCompatCheckBox** of V7 library

> app:buttonTint="@color/YOUR_COLOR"

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"  
    app:buttonTint="@color/YOUR_COLOR" />
```

Answer (score 6):

It's specified by the drawables: [`android.R.drawable.checkbox_off_background`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.drawable.html#checkbox_off_background) and [`android.R.drawable.checkbox_on_background`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.drawable.html#checkbox_on_background)

Comment: Thank you for the specifics. I seemed to have trouble pinpointing those two properties as responsible. Thank you. +1

Comment: so how to change that color ?

Answer (score 1):

This will be the most efficient way.

android:buttonTint="@color/black"

Comment: tks... Só simple !