# Change Checkbox background in runtime-(Changing checkbox gradient colors in run time) android

Tags: android, checkbox, gradient

We know that in android application we can change background color of checkboxes by using `SetButtonDrawable` and a xml file.

This xml file can be define with gradients or a simple file that used images in drawables.
This article show a sample with Gradients: [Android: Set color of CheckBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11464143/android-set-color-of-checkbox)

And also this is another sample that i used:

```
 <item android:state_checked="true">
    <layer-list>
        <item>
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid android:color="#9b9b9b" />
                <corners android:radius="5dp" />

            </shape>
        </item>
        <item android:top="2dp" android:left="1.5dp" >
            <shape  android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
                <corners android:radius="5dp" />
                <size android:height="20dp" android:width="20dp" />
            </shape>
        </item>
        <item android:top="2dp" android:bottom="1dp" android:left="1.5dp">
            <shape  android:shape="rectangle">
                <gradient android:startColor="#ff7dbce9" android:endColor="#ff2578b3" android:angle="270" />
                <corners android:radius="5dp" />
                <size android:height="20dp" android:width="20dp" />
            </shape>
        </item>
        <item android:top="2dp" android:bottom="1dp" android:left="1.5dp">
            <shape  android:shape="rectangle">
                <gradient android:startColor="#ff7dbce9" android:endColor="#ff2578b3" android:angle="270" />
                <corners android:radius="5dp" />
                <size android:height="20dp" android:width="20dp" />
            </shape>
        </item>
        <item>
            <bitmap android:gravity="center" android:src="@drawable/tick_red_icon"/>
        </item>
    </layer-list>
</item>
<item >
    <layer-list>
        <item>
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid android:color="#9b9b9b" />
                <corners android:radius="5dp" />
            </shape>
        </item>
        <item android:top="2dp" android:left="1.5dp" >
            <shape  android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
                <corners android:radius="5dp" />
                <size android:height="20dp" android:width="20dp" />
            </shape>
        </item>
        <item android:top="2dp" android:bottom="2dp" android:left="1.5dp">
            <shape  android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid android:color="#e5e4e4" />
                <corners android:radius="5dp" />
                <size android:height="20dp" android:width="20dp" />
            </shape>
        </item>
    </layer-list>
</item>
```

Also we know that if we wanna change the gradient colors we need to define it as a `DrawableGradient` in runtime and then use this.

The question is this: How can we define some comlex gradients like above as `DrawableGradient` to have the ability that change them color on runtime?

Or if there is a bad solution is there any better solution that we set the background color of checkboxes and can changes their color on runtime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally by research I found this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8018435/android-how-to-change-a-layer-list-drawable) and based on this I developed a code that is this question's answer.

We have to define each layer in a separate xml file like this:

```
 <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item>
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid android:color="#9b9b9b" />
                <corners android:radius="5dp" />

            </shape>
        </item>
        <item android:top="2dp" android:left="1.5dp" >
            <shape  android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
                <corners android:radius="5dp" />
                <size android:height="20dp" android:width="20dp" />
            </shape>
        </item>
        <item android:top="2dp" android:bottom="1dp" android:left="1.5dp" android:id="@+id/mainImage">
            <shape  android:shape="rectangle">
                <gradient android:startColor="#ff7dbce9" android:endColor="#ff2578b3" android:angle="270" />
                <corners android:radius="5dp" />
                <size android:height="20dp" android:width="20dp" />
            </shape>
        </item>
        <item android:top="2dp" android:bottom="1dp" android:left="1.5dp" android:id="@+id/TheinImage">
            <shape  android:shape="rectangle">
                <gradient android:startColor="#ff7dbce9" android:endColor="#ff2578b3" android:angle="270" />
                <corners android:radius="5dp" />
                <size android:height="20dp" android:width="20dp" />
            </shape>
        </item>
        <item>
            <bitmap android:gravity="center" android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_ca_dis"/>
        </item>
    </layer-list>
```

and then by retrieving them on run-time we can change their items.(Layer is the name of my xml file)

```
GradientDrawable gd = new GradientDrawable
            (GradientDrawable .Orientation .TopBottom,
             new int[]{Color.Red , Color.Green });
        gd.SetStroke (10, Color.Blue );
LayerDrawable ld = (LayerDrawable) Resources .GetDrawable  (Resource .Drawable.Layer   );
        bool testfactor = ld.SetDrawableByLayerId (Resource .Id.mainImage , gd);
```

Now, by using `StateListDrawable` we can define witch state is related to witch layer:

```
    StateListDrawable states = new StateListDrawable();
        states.AddState (new int[] {Android .Resource .Attribute .StateChecked },
        ld);
        states.AddState(new int[] { },
        Resources .GetDrawable (Resource .Drawable .ic_menu_ca_dis   ) );
```

Now, you can join changing this xml in runtime :)