# Changing checkbox style to Cross - Android

Tags: java, android

I have been coding an Android Application, and using `CheckBox` for GUI.

Generally, the style of `CheckBox` is a `green colored tick`, but I want to make it `red colored cross`.

How to do it.? Please Help.

Comment: I want to change the style.. not the color. Changing color is just a part of question. main part is how to change the the `tick` to `X`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set any color of tick mark of Checkbox. but you need to make the custom checkbox for that.

Look [here](http://vimaltuts.com/android-tutorial-for-beginners/android-custom-checkbox) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11464143/android-set-color-of-checkbox/11464319#11464319).

Source : [Android: Set color of CheckBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11464143/android-set-color-of-checkbox/11464319#11464319)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <item android:state_checked="true" 
    android:drawable="@drawable/cbchk_blue"
    android:state_focused="false">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="@color/blue_dark" />
        <gradient  android:endColor="@color/white" android:startColor="@color/blue_dark" android:type="sweep"  />
        <size android:height="30dp" android:width="30dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:state_checked="true" 
    android:drawable="@drawable/cbchk_blue"
    android:state_focused="true">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="@color/white" />
        <gradient  android:endColor="@color/white" android:startColor="@color/blue_dark" android:type="sweep"  />
        <size android:height="30dp" android:width="30dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:state_checked="false" 
    android:drawable="@drawable/cbunchk_blue"
    android:state_focused="false">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="@color/blue_dark" />
        <size android:height="30dp" android:width="30dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:state_checked="false" 
    android:drawable="@drawable/cbunchk_blue"
    android:state_focused="true">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="@color/white" />
        <size android:height="30dp" android:width="30dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

Comment: How to do it using Java codes.?

Comment: What does the `<shape >` tag do.? I have not been through that tag before.

Comment: @VeerShubhranshuShrivastav Use the <shape> tag to create a drawable in XML with for ex: rounded corners. (You can do other stuff with the shape tag like define a color gradient as well)

Answer (score 2):

Take a Custom Drawable selector with one image for unchecked state and another for checked state and set it as drawable resource for your Checkbox

Example:

Create a xml file in **res/drawable** folder

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/crossimagecheckbox" />
    <item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@drawable/uncheckecheckbox" />

</selector>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a selector for checkbox.

in layout checkbox add the following:

```
android:background="@drawable/checkbox_selector"
```

in checkbox_selector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/normal_picture" />
    <item android:state_checked="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/checked_picture" />
</selector>
```

Now create normal_picture and checked_picture according to your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

I believe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3965484/custom-checkbox-image-android) link is highly relevant. Read Jean's answer:

> Checkboxes being children of Button you can just give your checkbox a
>   background image with several states as described here, under "Button
>   style":
>   http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html
>
> ...and exemplified here:
>   http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList