# Setting background colour on check box in android

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to set the background colour of a check box when it has been checked then and if it is unchecked then to remove that colour.

Can anybody help me find the Id of the checkbox then to check if it is checked. I have set in my XML sheet `android:onClick="handleCheckBoxClick"`

For you to get an idea of how it looks I have roughly 25 check boxes.
which I need the same doing to them when they are pressed.

Is it possible to have one block of code or would it need to be repeated for each checkbox?

EDIT:
Forgot to mention this is within a fragment (if that makes any difference)

```
public void handleCheckBoxClick(View view) {
        int chkID = view.getId();

        if (){

        }else{

        }

        //find which checkbox was checked then get its id
        /*
         * if checked then
         * change background colour to blue
         * if unchecked then
         * remove background colour
         * 
         */
    }
```

The colour part i'll try myself as do need to learn .

Comment: use drawable for setting background.

Comment: you can set background color or you may set image from drawable

Comment: use an xml with selector. Refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11464319/1554935)

Comment: thanks for quick replys everyone, but just to clarify its not the button part i would like change but the background of where the text is

Answer (score 2):

The preferable way is to use a [custom checkbox](http://vimaltuts.com/android-tutorial-for-beginners/android-custom-checkbox). To set background in both `checked state` and `unchecked state` by simply using drawable XML file.

Here is an [another simple example](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/android-app-builder/create-a-custom-checkbox-in-your-android-app/) to do it. The following picture is taken from this page:

[image: ]]

Comment: First link is broken and pointing to something pretty sketchy looking.

Answer (score 0):

if you are interested in changing the background color of the checkbox(button) use

```
mycheckbox.setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.otherbackground);
```

where someother background is an image in the drawable folder to which background you want your checkbox to be changed

try following

```
mycheckbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
            boolean isChecked) {

        if (isChecked) {
            mycheckbox.setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.imageWhenActive);
        }
        else
        {
            mcheckbox.setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.imageWheninactive);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is Your Answer

```
public void handleCheckBoxClick(View view) {
    CheckBox chkBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(view.getId());
    if(chkBox.isChecked())
    {
        chkBox.setBackgroundColor(color.blue);
//or
       chkBox.setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.imagechk);
    }
    else
    {
        chkBox.setBackgroundColor(color.red);
//or
 chkBox.setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.imageunchk);
    }
}
```