# Android- How to change the text of a button when it is pressed?

Tags: android, checkbox, android-drawable, xml-drawable

I have a Checkbox that will be the button Follow/Following of my app.
How can I change the text of this button in the XML file without have to create a image for that?
Is this possible?

Here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/follow_card" android:state_checked="false">

        </item>
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/following_card" android:state_checked="true"/>
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/follow_card"/>
    </selector>
```

Follow_card/Following_card are two diferent XML drawable files defining the shape of the button

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12889729/change-checkbox-background-color-in-android

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19447523/setting-background-colour-on-check-box-in-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd do it programmatically. As the other comment says, you'll need to create an `onClickListener`, this way:

```
CheckBox your_checkbox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.your_checkbox_id);
your_checkbox.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { 
  @Override
  public void onClick(View view) {
    if (view.isChecked())
      your_checkbox.setText("Hey I'm checked!");
    else
      your_checkbox.setText("I'm not checked!");
  }
});
```