# checkbox.setClickable(false) doesn't work in android

Tags: android

I am trying a custom based listview which has a text and checkbox. I would like to disable the checkbox's clickable feature. So that the user will only be able to click on the item row rather than clicking on the checkbox.

I tried the following:

```
 holder.checkbox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
 holder.checkbox.setClickable(false);
```

This is not disabling the clickable. How do I fix this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this

```
   holder.checkbox.setEnabled(false);
```

for dealing with the colours of the checkbox(as asked by you in comments) see this [Android: Set color of CheckBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11464143/android-set-color-of-checkbox)

Comment: yup,it is telling you that your checkbox is disabled

Comment: Is this the only way? Is there any other work around?

Comment: you want to disable a checkbox but don't want your users to see it that it is disabled.You will need to set some .xml file for it

Comment: Yep. I just want to disable the clickable part in the checkbox.

Comment: I tried what ever you recommended. It is not working. I can't see the changes I have done in my XML.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59922/discussion-between-divide-by-zero-and-thedevman).

Answer (score 1):

Use `setEnable(true/false)` instead of clickable