# How to change the text and the box color of my checkbox programmatically?

Tags: java, javascript, android, checkbox

I build an app with multi calculation system and it need every thing filled to get the result, so if the user left the `checkbox` without selection i would to inform him by making the text and the box of the `checkbox` change to "Red"
like the picture in the link:

[image: https://s15.postimg.org/kej9uc457/checkbox.jpg]

if we assume my checkbox is "Yes", so how to make code for this and another one to rerun it back to it's original one?

---

I can make an custom xml file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/option_unselected" android:state_checked="false" android:color="#ff0000"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/option_selected"   android:state_checked="true"/>
```

I know how to make the condition of checking:

```
if(yes.isChecked())
        {check.setButtonDrawable(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(
                R.drawable.custom_checkbox));}
else
        {check.setButtonDrawable(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(
                R.drawable.custom_checkbox));}
```

but in this case i need two somethings:

1- checkbox image like the default one on android, then making it's box "red"

2- I need a code to make it return back to default one with black text and box

,, So how can I do that? or if anyone have another solution for my problem?

Comment: Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/11464319/1197454

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can create another set of xml called custom_red_checkbox.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/option_unselected_red" android:state_checked="false" android:color="#ff0000"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/option_selected"   android:state_checked="true"/>
```

and your code modify to

```
if(yes.isChecked())
        {check.setButtonDrawable(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(
                R.drawable.custom_checkbox));}
else
        {check.setButtonDrawable(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(
                R.drawable.custom_red_checkbox));}
```