# I need change the color to border of the check box,Because it is in white color

Tags: android, android-layout

I have check box in my contacts list to select that. But check box is in white color,it is not visible...So i need to change that border to black color...Please help me to change the code

This is my layout code

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:divider="?android:dividerVertical"
    android:showDividers="middle"
    android:dividerPadding="5dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >


    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/contact_image"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:src="@drawable/contacts_image" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"

        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="0dp"
            android:paddingTop="1dp"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/mobile_number"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="0dp"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/check_box"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/check_box_width"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:clickable="true"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

This is my style.xml code

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
        <item name="background">@color/scandal</item>
        <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTitleText</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyActionBarTitleText" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ActionBarCompat">
        <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">50dp</item>
        <item name="android:orientation">horizontal</item>
    </style>


    <style name="DashboardButton">
        <item name="android:layout_gravity">center_vertical</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center_horizontal</item>
        <item name="android:drawablePadding">2dp</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">16dp</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#ff29549f</item>
        <item name="android:background">@null</item>

    </style>

    <style name="FooterBar">
        <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">40dp</item>
        <item name="android:orientation">horizontal</item>
        <item name="android:background">#dedede</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Divider">
        <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">1dp</item>
        <item name="android:background">?android:attr/listDivider</item>
    </style>


</resources>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11464143/android-set-color-of-checkbox

Comment: It shows an error in <item name="android:button">?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple</item>

Answer (score 0):

instead changing the default in style xml file. do this.

create this your_custom.xml file and and save it in drawable folder

your_custom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/unselected" android:state_checked="false"><color android:textColor="#your_color" />
    </item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/selected" android:state_checked="true"><color android:textColor="#your_color" />
    </item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/uncheck"></item>
   <!-- default -->

</selector>
```

you will have to create three images for checkbox display 
1.selected
2.unselect
3.uncheck

after all this done set attribute to your checkbox in layout

```
android:button="@drawable/your_custom"
```

Comment: yes. you will have to specify your color in hash codes.

Comment: Ya it works....but it is in small size...so i want to change the size..Please help me

Comment: That must be bcoz images used by you are small. check out this link (http://android-holo-colors.com). just choose your color. select checkbox, download files and put them in your project folders respectively.

Comment: Hmm k...i will check that