# Custom checkboxes in android multichoice dialog

Tags: android

I'm building a small app which displays a multichoice dialog. What i need to do, is to change the checkbox image. I want to replace the green tick, with my custom bitmap. Is there a simple way to do this? Can it be done without creating a custom adapter? Thanks.

Comment: You can style your checkbox widget instead. Check http://stackoverflow.com/a/10139809/1082344

Comment: Not *can* but **should**.

Comment: [check this library](http://androidcustomviews.com/portfolio/multichoiceadapter/) may be it helped you.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem?

Comment: I don't think, there is a simple solution for that. I did it the right way - created a custom layout and a custom array adapter

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code to show a dialog box to user:

```
btn2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            Builder alert2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            alert2.setTitle("pick one of below");
            alert2.setSingleChoiceItems(items, 0, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
                {
                    itemsCecked[which] = true;
                }
            });
            alert2.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
            {   
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
                {
                    for(int i=0; i<items.length ; i++)
                    {
                        if(itemsCecked[i]==true)
                        {
                            txt.setText(items[i]);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
```

use this in     oncreate()     method.