# Inconsistent checkbox appearance

Tags: android, checkbox

I am making an app with the following properties:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="22" />
```

Currently I am using 3 different methods to display Checkboxes, and all of them appear differently!

**1) Inflated from XML:**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <CheckBox 
        android:id="@+id/dialog_fish_autoeat"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="true"
        android:text="@string/dialog_shop_autoeat"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Code:

```
// Passing null as the parent, as this is the layout for an AlertDialog
final View inflate = game.getLayoutInflater().inflate(
            R.layout.dialog_fish, null);
builder.setView(inflate);
builder.show();
```

The result is a Checkbox that looks quite good as it fits with the style of the dialog:

[image: Checkbox 1 - looks good]

**2) Created in code:**

```
final CheckBox autoEquip;
autoEquip = new CheckBox(game);
autoEquip.setText(R.string.dialog_shop_autoequip);
autoEquip.setChecked(newStrength > oldStrength);
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(game);
builder.setView(autoEquip);
builder.show();
```

The result is a checkbox that looks dark and out-of-place compared to the dialog it's added to:

[image: Checkbox 2 - too dark]

Interestingly, 1 and 2 used to look the same before I started supporting later versions of Android.

**3) XML and Activity.setContentView:**

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:background="@color/menu_bg"
    tools:context=".Menu" >

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/endgame_submit_score"
        android:text="@string/endgame_submit_score"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="true" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The activity preview in Android Studio shows the expected result:

[image: Checkbox 3 preview - looks good]

This Checkbox uses yet another style, but in this case it fits with the dark style of the Activity.

However, when I test the app on my Moto G, the checkbox doesn't appear:

[image: Checkbox 4 - not there]

Can anyone shed some light on this? Why do the Checkboxes appear in these 3 different styles, and how can I control them? Why does the last Checkbox not appear at all?

---

**EDIT:** This last problem seems to be caused by my Activity using a style that inherits from Theme.AppCompat:

```
<style name="Menu" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat" >
```

If I remove the parent theme, the Checkbox reappears. So, presumably there is some problem with my appcompat setup. Here's how I'm adding the dependency in build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
}
```

Comment: Give your CheckBox a `custom style`, once and for all.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm more concerned with why this is happening - in particular the 3rd case, where the checkbox is invisible.

Comment: Possibly, your Moto G uses a customized theme?

Comment: It's certainly a theme-related problem, but I'm not sure what's wrong exaclty. I've edited the question and will continue to investigate...

Comment: Reading [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10135499/android-checkbox-style) may help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is caused by changing the version of the v7 support library.

If my `build.gradle` contains the line:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.0.0'
```

then all the Checkboxes look the same, but as soon as I upgrade it to, say:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0'
```

The appearance of the Checkboxes changes.

In the case of the disappearing Checkbox, it is because the Checkbox is completely BLACK, therefore it blends in with the background.