# How to apply style to checkbox from code

Tags: android, checkbox, android-checkbox

i have check box

```
                <CheckBox
                    android:id="@+id/chk1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textSize="12dp"
                    android:theme="@style/MyCheckboxTheme"/>
```

From above code i am able to set the `android:theme` to my checkbox. But i want to set this `theme` from code side.

I have write this for Checkbox from code side:

```
    chk1.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
    chk1.setHintTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
    chk1.setTextSize(12);
```

But how can i apply `style` to checkbox through code?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the API level that you are targeting, you need to create a new style, and point your checkbox style to this.

Please refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10139809/4180965), as this shows a **detailed** explanation of this.