# multichoice dialog with click order

Tags: android, dialog

I want to do a multichoice dialog with a listener in which order I pressed the options. How can I do that?

```
String[] multiChoiceItems = 
getResources().getStringArray(R.array.dialog_choice_array_monday);
boolean[] checkedItems = {false, false, false, false, false, false, false};
new AlertDialog.Builder(NewScheduleActivity.this)

.setTitle(getString(R.string.main_dialog_multi_choice_monday))
.setMultiChoiceItems(multiChoiceItems, checkedItems, null)
.setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.dialog_ok), null)
.setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.dialog_cancel), null)
 .show();       
        }
```

Comment: Did you try custom dialog? See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13341560/how-to-create-a-custom-dialog-box-in-android

Comment: @nhoxbypass The Problem is to listen to the order of the pressed option.. I don't know how to realize this

Comment: Please let me know if my solution below is what you're looking for

Comment: @KJNewtown unfortunately not... I am searching for a solution in which sequence/order I clicked the items

Comment: Yes! so you need to create a new array for the sequence, and by using my solution, in the onClick Listener,  just add the code inside to add the selected elements in the sequenceArray!
At the end, this array will contain the data in the order it was selected.
Do you see the possibilities?

Comment: Ahh Yes. Exactly what I searched for. Thanks! @KJNewtown

Comment: Nice!
I completed my post below with the updated solution

Answer (score 0):

This should help:

```
 .setMultiChoiceItems(multiChoiceItems, null, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {

});
```

when you'll start typing new DialogeInterface.OnMul...... it will autoimplement the abstract method:

```
onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which, boolean isChecked)
```

I think you can use null instead of your checkedItems array, depending if you need to use the data from this array or not.

**What you need to do:**

Create a new array for the sequence, and in the onClick Listener, just add the code inside to add the selected element in the sequenceArray! At the end, this array will contain the data in the order it was selected.

```
   String[] multiChoiceItems = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.dialog_choice_array_monday);
    ArrayList<String> sequenceArray = new ArrayList<>();
new AlertDialog.Builder(NewScheduleActivity.this)

                        .setTitle(getString(R.string.main_dialog_multi_choice_monday))
                        .setMultiChoiceItems(multiChoiceItems, null, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which, boolean isChecked) {
                                sequenceArray.add(multiChoiceItems[which])
                            }
                        }
                        .setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.dialog_ok), null)
                        .setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.dialog_cancel), null)
                        .show();
            }
```

Android website: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/DialogInterface.html

Comment: I am really new add this stuff... Could you please write me the code for a good sequenceArray?

Comment: Thank you! Is there any way to modify the checkboxes of the multichoice?

Comment: The layout you mean? maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10139809/1082344